# Categories and Tags for Lithium-Themed site

Tags: blogdown

I've got a blog using Hugo's "Lithium" theme. I need to add some taxonomy, i.e. Categories and Tags, which is not supported in this simple theme.

So I need to know how to either:

- modify the Lithium theme to include Categories and Tags (although I'm reluctant to make any changes I might have to maintain myself through future upgrades*), or else
- change the theme of this site to another theme that supports Categories and Tags - for example [this one](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/mainroad/) would do nicely if I could simply rebuild the site with a different theme.

* *I've checked [the Blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html#how-to), Section 2.5.2, where it explains how to "Display categories and tags in a post if provided in its YAML" - indeed that is what I want to do - but I'm unclear from those instructions where exactly to put this code snippet, and if it's just a one-time fix, or a procedure I'll have to repeat in future.*

Comment: I'd suggest picking an approach and starting work and/or research on implementation, but as it stands this isn't an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: To answer your question "but I'm unclear from those instructions where exactly to put this code snippet, and if it's just a one-time fix, or a procedure I'll have to repeat in future": it is a one-time fix in `single.html`.

Comment: Categories and tags are like the "default" functionality for most hugo blog themes I've seen. I would suggest trying other themes first, instead of implementing them by yourself.

Comment: Yes @TC Zhang : i would prefer at this point to switch to a bit more sophisticated theme -i really like [this Mainroad theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/mainroad/), but i don't know how to rebuild my existing site (which already has a good amount of content) with the new theme.  Is there a n00b-friendly explainer on how to do this that you can point me to?

Comment: It's actually not hard and someone has asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175938/ Have a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, @TCZhang -took your advice and it *almost* worked; have posted the hair in this soup as [an issue](https://github.com/Vimux/Mainroad/issues/135) on the theme's Github repo, where dev is suggesting that i fiddle with some config file(s) -which i've tried, in various ways, but w/o success thus far.  Still digging!

Comment: You are almost there. Could you upload your website repo to GitHub so I can have a look?

Comment: OK @TCZhang : just created [this repo](https://github.com/ludwa6/blog2) of new static site created using Hugo w/ Mainroad theme... Only Github didn't like how many files the site contained, so it's in the form of a single .ZIP archive.  Can you see diffs in main menu bar and title formatting, vs [Demo site](https://hugothemes.gitlab.io/mainroad/) online?

Comment: Hi, your site is perfectly fine. It's just that the theme is responsive to different sizes of the displayed screen. It shows a dropdown Menu when the width is below ~765 pixels. You can hit F12 in chrome and test the displays using "toggle device toolbar"

Comment: Ha! right you are, @TCZhang : in fact i was viewing site in a frame, but when i opened it in its own window, everything appeared exactly as it should.  Now i can get on with my real work; thanks a heap, mate!